# Calling functions

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

this may sound proper nooby, but I'm having some trouble with python functions.

i do a level computer science and I'm making a currency converter using a dictionary to define the exchange rates of the currencies.

for each conversion, i have made a function that does all the calculations etc for the converting. for example, if i wanted to convert sterling to euro, my script would use the SE function. after i have defined all the functions, there is a algorithm that says

```
if (i == 'SE'):
    return(SE)
```

because SE is the function name for this conversion. however, when i run this code, it tells me that `return` cannot be used outside of a function, so is there a way in calling up the function?

my code without using functions can be found here: http://pastebin.com/bt23MeTn

my code with the function attempt can be found here: 
http://pastebin.com/sLFwrDT8

for those of you who are wondering why I'm using a dictionary, its because my teacher said that the exchange rates can change anytime so using a dictionary will mean the user only has to change the dict entry instead of changing each individual formula. i suppose i could make a scraper algorithm to scrape a website for each rate, but that'll probably be in my next version :)

Comment: Instead of links to the code, post your code straight here.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: Python doesn't require that many parentheses, `if i == 'SE': return SE` will do just fine syntax-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is used to return variables from a [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

To call a function you have simply to write the name of the function with the input parameters in the round brackets. In your case `SE` function has not input parameters so you have to call it as follow:

```
if i == 'SE':
    SE()
```